# How do I transfer Smalltalk files between computers?

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I need to transfer some Smalltalk files between two different computers, both running Cincom VisualWorks. (I'm not sure if this matters, but one is a Windows 7 machine, and the other is a Mac). How do I transfer my project? Should I simply replace the image in the second machine with the image in the first? Can I simply transfer the project itself, without taking along the entire image? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can copy a project without copying the entire image. There are several ways to do that, depending on the Smalltalk IDE you are using.

In Visualworks, you can transfer a project via:

- source code repository (Store)
- parcels
- .st files

The easiest way to copy an entire project (and just that project) in Visualworks is to export it into one or more parcels. These can be loaded into another image. There is excellent documentation on this in the Visualworks documents provided with their distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply copy a whole VisualWorks directory from one machine to another, because both image, source and change files (including parcels and other) are portable and therefore directly transferable between different platforms and operating systems.

If you have VisualWorks already installed on the second machine, copying just an image and its changes file will suffice.